# How to download source files for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Ubuntu source code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106818/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-source-code)

I am new to Ubuntu, and recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit version.
I want to know the steps to download the source files for 11.10 to my Laptop.

Tried `sudo apt-get` but failed to download.

Answer (score 1):

You can download source ISO's [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/source/current/source/). Also, you can use `sudo apt-get source [package]`, but you must first uncomment/create lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that begin with `deb-src` to enable to source archives.

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal:

Update the Package Index: The APT package index is essentially a database of available packages from the repositories defined in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. To update the local package index with the latest changes made in repositories, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Upgrade Packages: Over time, updated versions of packages currently installed on your computer may become available from the package repositories (for example security updates). To upgrade your system, first update your package index as outlined above, and then type:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To get a source:

```
apt-get source <package name>
```

Comment: Oh i thought source code :D